# Trying to set makeprg in vim for yuml filetypes, works manually, not working in vimrc

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get the following entry working in my .vimrc:

```
 autocmd FileType yuml set makeprg=yuml\ -i\ %\ -o\ %<\.pdf\ -f\ pdf\ &\ sleep\ 1\;\ evince\ %<.pdf\ &
```

It doesn't work and whenever I type :make, it uses some default options from the yuml utility.
However when I type:

```
set makeprg=yuml\ -i\ %\ -o\ %<\.pdf\ -f\ pdf\ &\ sleep\ 1\;\ evince\ %<.pdf\ &
```

manually in vim, the command does work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Martin

---

Edit: I forgot to explicitly define the yuml filetype. So what I needed to do was add the following line to the .vimrc file:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.yuml set filetype=yuml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what exactly is wrong, but in a scripted autocmd, I would skip the escaping issue and use `:let` instead:

```
:autocmd FileType yuml let &makeprg = 'yuml -i % -o %<.pdf -f pdf & sleep 1; evince %<.pdf &'
```

Also, check that the filetype is correctly set with `:set ft?`

Comment: Thanks you got me on the right path, I forgot to define the filetype. So basically all I had to define was:

    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.yuml set filetype=yuml